# Sql Server STUFF - is it supposed to work with position > 8000?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Compare these two statements

```
select stuff(convert(varchar(max),replicate('a', 10000)),8001,1,'b')
select stuff(convert(varchar(max),replicate('a', 10000)),8000,1,'b')
```

Output

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa...
NULL
```

Books Online says `start can be of type bigint.`  Why such a large range if it won't even work for 8001?

If the behaviour is different between 2005, 2008, 2008 R2 and Denali, then I would like to know the actual behaviour of each version.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[`REPLICATE ('a', 10000)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174383.aspx) will produce a 8000 characters string:

> If string_expression is not of type
>   varchar(max) or nvarchar(max),
>   REPLICATE truncates the return value
>   at 8,000 bytes. To return values
>   greater than 8,000 bytes,
>   string_expression must be explicitly
>   cast to the appropriate large-value
>   data type.

Try `REPLICATE (cast('a' as varchar(max)), 10000)`.